# Photoview - I want to get the relative x and y coordinate after zoomed in

Tags: java, android, image-manipulation

I am developing an app using Android Studio 3. This app have a floor plan image and grid over it. Both are added with Canvas into PhotoView by https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView.

Scenario 1 : without zoom in,
When the user click a cell of the grid , the clicked cell will be Painted with black. This has no problem.

Scenario 2 : with zoomed in,
When the user click a cell of the grid , the cell will be Painted with black but different cell, not the clicked one.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                int column = (int) (event.getX() / cellWidth);
                int row = (int) (event.getY() / cellHeight);                    

                if (column < numColumns && row < numRows) {
                    cellChecked[column][row] = !cellChecked[column][row];                        
                    drawGrid();                        
                }
            }
return false;
}
```

So, the problem is on Scenario 2. The cell clicked should Painted black after PhotoView was zoom in.

Comment: see `OnPhotoTapListener`

Comment: I don't quite understand, the value from the code, xResult and yResult is less than zero. How to implement into my code?

   float xResult = (x - displayRect.left)
                                / displayRect.width();
                        float yResult = (y - displayRect.top)
                                / displayRect.height();

                        if (mPhotoTapListener != null) {
                            mPhotoTapListener.onPhotoTap(mImageView, xResult, yResult);
                        }

Comment: I think I need the absolute x,y coordinate which is the x,y coordinate same as without zoom in.. This x,y based on PhotoView coordinate, not onScreen coordinate

Comment: so the listener passes values outside 0..1 range?

Comment: yeah, in this https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/photoview/src/main/java/com/github/chrisbanes/photoview/OnPhotoTapListener.java also mentioned, it is percentage (xResult and yResult)

Comment: no, they say "percentage", percentage cannot be < 0 (0%) or > 1 (100%)

Comment: it is a float by the way, I use breakpoint there and the it is 0 to 1 value

Comment: this what is asked above: `"so the listener passes values outside 0..1 range?"`

Comment: yes, it is 0 to 1

Comment: so what is your problem actually? cannot you multiply those values by `Drawable` width / height?

Comment: You rock pskink! Finally success to Paint the cell. TQ very much! I actually read your answer from several question related to mine, but your understanding is outstanding.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `Kotlin` code:

```
val displayRect = photoView.displayRect

val relativeX = ((event.x - displayRect.left) / displayRect.width())
val relativeY = ((event.y - displayRect.top) / displayRect.height())
```